# How to export LaTeX from org-mode to HTML using dvipng instead of mathjax GLOBALLY?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

The doc string for `org-export-with-latex` describes how to select mathjax, verbatim output, or not to export LaTeX at all, although it goes further to say:

> If you prefer, you can also request that LaTeX fragments are processed
>   into small images that will be inserted into the browser page.

But no value is actually listed for requesting that.  I've tried setting `org-export-with-latex` to `'dvipng` and `"dvipng"`, with no success either way.

The only way I've obtained the desired result is with `#+OPTIONS: tex:dvipng`.  Unfortunately, that method would require modifying each and every org-mode file.

What's proper way to specify the `dvipng` export mechanism globally?

Note: Actually, no value for `org-export-with-latex` seems to have any effect.  Without `#+OPTIONS: tex:dvipng`, I always get mathjax, unless I set `org-html-mathjax-template` to `""`, in which case I get `verbatim`-style output -- again, regardless of the value of `org-export-with-latex`.

Emacs 26.1, org 9.1.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. For others encountering this, I needed to use the variable specific to the `html` backend:

```
(setq-default org-html-with-latex `dvipng)
```